# Why can't I sign up for a team without a credit-card?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I want to signup for the teams 14-day trial for my organisation but it's requiring a credit-card before I even sign up.

I understand wanting people to pay for it -- Although I'm really hoping it's not requiring me to provide a CC in hopes I'll signup with the intent of a trial and then forget about it to keep getting billed -- but my manager doesn't know that we need it yet and I don't have access to a company credit card and won't get given one.

It's a lot easier to convince someone to buy something if you can show them first instead of telling them about it.

Comment: Fair point about the show vs. tell, but... If you're gonna give this a fair shot you're gonna have to get a few other people on board doncha think?

Comment: @Shog9 Totally. Those people are already onboard and don't have credit cards.

Comment: Put a personal card in and just make sure you cancel before the trial is up?

Comment: @gahooa - I'd move onto something else before I gave my personal credit card

Comment: Will the signup process accept a $10 gift-card credit-card? Worst case you're out the gift-card and not a recurring charge.

Comment: @Freiheit those are debit cards, so if there is a requirement for a debit card, it won't go through.

Comment: Auto-recurring charges stemming from trials are not pleasant.

Comment: I wondered the same thing...especially since its a free trial..I hated it.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, I don't know your situation.  I am baffled by your instant-decision to move on rather than use a personal card for a free trial that won't bill you.  And if they do bill you, dispute it.  It's your test account?   Just seems like a non-issue.  Then again, this whole thread seems like a non-issue.

Comment: @gahooa - Instant decision, maybe, but it’s  based on numerous past experiences... identity theft, privacy, lost time required to dispute charges... etc. just not worth going around that block again for a “free” trial.  That’s just me, feel free to knock yourself out.  Once you go through it you might become gun shy too.

Comment: BTW - totally understand why SO requires it.  That’s fine.  Not trying to argue otherwise.  It’s a business decision that protects their product.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, it makes sense.  I admittedly approach it from the perspective of having the corporate card in my wallet (and authorizing the bill payment for it too).  Have a great day!

Answer (score 46):

While there are several reasons that we require a credit card upfront, there is one primary driving decision. And that is that it's a, potentially temporary, deliberate constraint we put up to lessen the burden on our architecture and focus just on Teams that are more "bought in" to the product.

Until we procure more Teams-specific hardware, we have confidence in our ability to comfortably support a finite number of Teams. By putting up a requirement for a credit card, we reduce the number of people who are just poking around.

But, as you noted, we do lose out on people like yourself and it's quite possible that we change this requirement in the future.

Comment: *deliberate constraint we put up to lessen the burden on our architecture and focus just on Teams that are more "bought in" to the product.* can I have that in non marketing please?

Comment: @Liam They don't want people to create a team (which has to use hardware somewhere) and then go "Ah yeah, this is cool" and never use it again, thus eating up hardware for nothing. So they gate it with a credit card to scare those people off. It makes sense, but I wish there was a happy medium.

Comment: @Liam: "We're prioritising paid customers."

Comment: paying customers rather ? :D

Comment: I think it makes sense to leave the requirement in place.

Comment: @Pac0 If the customer doesn't get _paid_, they won't have the means to continue being a _paying_ customer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, true, but insufficient to communicate the real intent behind the decision.OP put it best, imho.

Comment: To be fair to stackoverflow, Most of the trail products from Microsoft, Amazon, Google  requires us to key in our credit card. But luckily we can ask stackoverflow about it but not the others.